# Distributed configuration in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function (written in Python) that needs to read some config. The config is essentially a dictionary (map) of strings => values.

Example:

```
config = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
  'key3': ['value31', 'value32', 'value33']
}
```

I want to be able to edit this config without performing a re-deploy of my Google Cloud Function.

Ideally, I'd like to store this config somewhere so that I can read it later when necessary. Does Google have something like this already?

One thing I can think of is just using something like GCS to store a .json/.yaml file and reading it periodically, but I wanted to check if there were other ways of storing this config. Especially if Google has some sort of distributed config mechanism already built.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a special purpose service for distributing configuration values to Cloud Functions.

As you supposed, [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage) is a very straightforward way to handle this.

You can also consider a managed Redis instance with [Cloud Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore).  A small JSON string stored in a Redis database could work out nicely for your system.

Of course, Redis has a different a notion of "durability" than GCS -- so you will want to weigh your options here.

*PS*: [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore) is yet another option.  It is fully managed & free with small amounts of data.  This is, in a certain sense, overkill -- but it *would* work.

Comment: Durability is definitely necessary. Ideally a Web UI to change the file without having to re-upload would be good

Comment: Don't forget to think about invalidation. If you read your config and store it in global variable, if you change your config on GCS (or elsewhere), how do you take into account the new one? I do this for BigQuery query storage, and I read the GCS file everytime that I need to perform the query. So I haven't cache!